Trying to Authenticate my React App with react-auth-kit
I want to use a cookie based authentication, I can see some cookies created in the browser but the    isAuthenticated state is not changing.
import useSignIn from 'react-auth-kit/hooks/useSignIn';
import useIsAuthenticated from 'react-auth-kit/hooks/useIsAuthenticated'



    const signIn = useSignIn();
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated()
if (signIn({
                auth: {
                    token: data.access_token,
                    type: 'Bearer',
                    expiresAt: data.expires_in

                },
                // refresh: data.refresh_token,
                userState: { name: 'React User', uid: 123456 }
            })) {
                // Redirect or do-something
                console.log('Success but is user authenticated : ', isAuthenticated);

                handleClose();
            }

Here are the cookies
cookies
